# Regexp: if there's something in front of results, don't return the result

Tags: regex

in a page like

```
<img src="http://www.sito.com/folder/folderb/10/12/2014/text.html" alt="" />
<p>date 15/02/2015</p>
```

using the reg exp

```
$result = preg_match_all("/[0-9]{1,2}\/*\-*[0-9]{1,2}\/*\-*[0-9]{4}/", $page, $matches);
```

$matches returns

10/12/2014

15/02/2015

But as you can see, the first one is not a date, but it's a part of an url.
How can I change the regexp saying it that if in front of the single result there's a slash (/) it has not to return the date found?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$result = preg_match_all("~(?<![/\d-])[0-9]{1,2}[/-]?[0-9]{1,2}[/-]?[0-9]{4}~", $page, $matches);
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<![/\d-]) # Assert that the previous character is not a slash nor a digit nor a dash
[0-9]{1,2}  # Match 1-2 digits
[/-]?       # Match an optional slash or dash
[0-9]{1,2}  # Match 1-2 digits
[/-]?       # Match an optional slash or dash
[0-9]{4}    # Match 4 digits.
```

I've used `~` as a regex delimiter in order to avoid having to escape the slash in the regex.